Calculating the ratio of a material in two phases
Assume material A and material B can react in the solution: $\ce{A + B <=> AB}$ with a relatively small $K_d$. For some reason, the material B forms a phase by itself in the solution. Therefore, it forms an "potential trap" which can catch A. How to calculate the potential gradient and the ratio of A in two phases if the concentration of A and B, and $K_d$ is known?
I think this situation is not suitable for the formula $\mu_A = \mu^\theta + RT\ln x_A$ since the phase constructed by B is probably not an ideal solution for A.
Is there any theory that can treat this kind of problem?
PS: The reason why B can form a phase itself may be B molecules can interact with each other strongly. An example is the liquid-liquid phase separation caused by a protein. Therefore, in the phase formed by B, the concentration of B is high, but in another phase, A, B and AB are all soluble.

The system description is not fully clear. Cant you elaborate the question?

What do you mean when saying that B forms a phase by itself ?  Do you mean that for example, A and AB are soluble in water, and B is not soluble ?

@Maurice I think A, B, AB are all soluble in water, but if B can interact with each other strongly, it forms a phase in the solution. An example is the liquid-liquid phase separation formed by some kinds of proteins. I'll edit the question to make it clearer.

@Poutnik I've just added PS on my previous post, hope it clarifies the problem :). This question is quite abstract and may be treated as a soft question. Anything useful to the problem can be hypothesized.

Speaking of potential gradient suggests the system is not in the equilibrium yet, being rather a reaction kinetics and diffusion problem. Correct?

@Poutnik I do think so. Here I mean two questions: 1. I want to calculate the potential gradient which drives A enters B phase; 2. In the end, I want to know the ratio of A in two phases. The first problem is reaction kinetics, and the second question ask about the equilibrium state.

You need to define the boundary and initial conditions for the partial differential equations describing difussion in each of phases and eventually at the phase boundary as well. Overall, it might be  a bigger morsel you can swallow, figuratively.

You need more information. You already established the equilibrium in aqueous phase:
$$\ce{A(aq) + B(aq) <=> AB(aq)}\ \ \ K_1 = \mathrm{"small"}$$
You need a second equilibrium of B between the two phases. If the second phase is pure B, we have:
$$\ce{B(aq) <=> B(l)}\ \ \ \ K_2 = \mathrm{"unspecified"}$$
This would mean that the equilibrium concentration of aqueous B is fixed to a certain value (the solubility), just like with a saturated solution where some of the solute is present in the (pure) solid state.
If the concentration of B is fixed, the ratio of A and AB is fixed, too. If the solubility of B is higher, this favors formation of the AB species, if it is lower, this favors dissociation of the AB species.
However, you posit that A is soluble in the second phase. In that case, you need more equilibrium constants (partition coefficient for A, equilibrium constant for forming AB in the second phase). An example would be acid dissociation in two immiscible phases, such as water and diethylether.
